# How to import images in eclipse correctly

Tags: eclipse, image

I tried to resolve this by both manually just dragging the image to eclipse or getting to the import. But the images always happenes to be an Text file as the Image below shows. Please Help!

Go zoom in and you can see the image imported is a text file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sq9i.png)

and when i open it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnzAd.png)

Comment: Pls help me i need help! I need it!

Answer (score 0):

Go to File Location.
Right Click --> Properties.
In General Tab --> Open  With: --> Click `Change`
Then either from `recommended / Other Software` choose your application with which you want to open it.

Comment: I dont see general tab?

Comment: I think you are in Windows 8.

Comment: Check this link sir. http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1656463/switch-default-image-viewer-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

The file has been imported correctly. If you just want to use the image from your code you don't have to do anything.

You are opening the file using the text editor rather than an image viewer. To view the file try right clicking on the file and selecting 'Open With' and selecting 'System Editor'.